# Trying get the $clientId the client typed in the from to the model

Tags: php

I am struggling to get the clientId from the form to the model. I am using netbeans 11.1 and php 7.4. I am following a certain tutorial, here is what I have tried, first my model which extends the base Model that defines database connection:

```
<?php

   class Clients_Model extends Model {


       function __construct() {
           parent::__construct();
           $clientId = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $clientId);
       }

       public function run($clientId = null){
           $statement = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM client WHERE clientId 
                      = :clientId");
           $statement->execute(array(':clientId' => $clientId));
           $data = $statement->fetchAll();
           print_r($data);
       }
   }
?>
```

next is the controller:

```
<?php

    class Clients extends Controller {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function index(){
            $this->view->render('clients/index');
        }

        function run(){
            $this->model->run();
        }
    }
?>
```

and the view:

```
<div id="content">
<h3>Client Booking</h3>
    <form  action="clients/run" method="post">
        <label for="clientId">Client Id:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="clientId" id="clientId"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit"><br>
    </form>
</div>
```

the view is rendered in the render function as follows:

```
<?php

    class View {

        function __construct() {

        }

        public function render($name, $same = false){
            if ($same == true){
                require 'views/' .$name. '.php';
            }else{
                require 'views/header.php';
                require 'views/' .$name. '.php';
                require 'views/footer.php';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

and the error is get is as follows:

```
> Notice: Undefined variable: clientId in C:\xampp\htdocs\healthMentor\models\clients_model.php on line 8
Array ( )
```

Comment: make  sure $clientId is not null ? before use filter_input function ... what the value of $clientId before the filter_input function ??

Comment: $clientId is from the form in the view, I'm trying to get the value provided by the client through this variable to the model, I'm not really sure about it, can you help please

Comment: try to print the value of $clientId and see the result

Answer (score 1):

That's obvious because there is no such variable defined like the error message already mentioned. Look at

```
   function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       $clientId = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $clientId);
   }
```

You want to have the $clientId defined by using the variable $clientId which is never defined before. Are you sure you want to have the clientId in the constructor? Seems it's misplaced here since it's also never been used in further steps. Maybe you want to move it to the run function?